# Benefits using Struct over Methods to generate Views in SwiftUI

Tags: methods, struct, view, swiftui

I'm having some perfomance dips in my current project, and since XCode Instruments is kinda cryptic, I'm debating whether the fault is my way of drawing views or something else.

Specifically, since most of the times I'm reusing views like `Buttons` that have different styles, without having to resort to create an entire `struct`, I've been using a `class` with `static` methods, to generate the views I need. It also helps my code readability.

Does anybody know if there's a perfomance benefit in switching to a `struct` vs using a method to generate `Views`? Here's are some examples.

```swift
class ViewGenerators {
    static func standardButton(imageName: String, title: String, backgroundColor: Color = .white, _ callback: @escaping () -> Void) {
        Button(action: callback) {
              HStack {
                  Image(imageName)
                  // ...other custom modifiers
                  Text(title)
              }.background(backgroundColor)
        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
     var body: some View {
          VStack {
              // Method
              ViewGenerators.standardButton(
                  imageName: "chevron.left",
                  title: "Back"
              ) {
               //...do something
              }
              // Struct
              Button(action: { //...do something }) {
                  HStack {
                      Image(imageName)
                      // ...other custom modifiers
                      Text(title)
                  }.background(backgroundColor)
              }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
          }   
     }
}
```

Comment: Generic rule is: the smaller your UI components the better. So if you see there is a possibility to separate something into dedicated view (with own state/s or model, or w/o them) - do it.

Comment: @Asperi so there aren't any negative implications from using methods vs structs?

Comment: On view update method will alway regenerate content, however separated view might now (it depends on dynamic properties & equality), so there are differences. If they are negative or positive depends on context.

Answer (score 0):

For me, If I use stateless View unlogic only show data, I usually use function (method), If stateful view or stateless view have a lot of logic I use struct is child of View,